react-bootstrap is breaking the Content-Security-Policy
react-bootstrap is breaking my content security policy
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' ". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-PWDchvr22tNcOYtadhdjrBW7P/D88+aaP1+5cOZy0JQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
I don't want to use unsafe-inline and I don't know how to proceed further.
I installed react-bootstrap using npm "npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap" and I imported it into my react app.js using import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
versions:
"bootstrap": "^5.3.3"
"react-bootstrap": "^2.10.2"
